# Binomial GLM using caret train

Tags: r, glm, r-caret

I would like to fit a Binomial GLM on a certain dataset. Using glm(...,family=binomial) everything works fine however I would like to do it with the caret train() function. Unfortunately I get an unexpected error which I cannot get rid of.

```
library("marginalmodelplots")
library("caret")

MissUSA <- MissAmerica08[,c(2,4,6,7,8,10)]
formula <- cbind(Top10, 9-Top10)~.
glmfit <- glm(formula=formula, data=MissUSA, family=binomial())

trainfit <-train(form=formula,data=MissUSA,trControl=trainControl(method = "none"),   method="glm", family=binomial())
```

The error I get is:

> "Error : nrow(x) == length(y) is not TRUE"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`caret` doesn't support grouped data for a binomial outcome. You can expand the data into a factor variable that is binary (Bernoulli) data. Also, if you do that, you do not need to use `family=binomial()` in the call to `train`.

Max

Comment: Thank you for your response. I used a numerical vector and weights to get it working:
    `trainfit2<-train(form=Top10/9~.,data=MissUSA[,-7], family= binomial(),method="glm", trControl=trainControl(method = "none"),weights=rep(9,51))`

Comment: @topepo, is this still the case (no support for binomial family)?