# Fitting binomial glm in caret

Tags: r, glm, r-caret

I have voting data in the form of counts for OutcomeA and counts for OutcomeB (there are only two outcomes). I am using the formulation of the glm binomial family of models as suggested here: GLM for proportion data in r ( https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/89734/glm-for-proportion-data-in-r ) with the y variable being:

```
cbind (OutcomeA, OutcomeB)
```

I would like to use the caret package, to do some cross validation and generally handle the output for comparative purposes, as suggested here:
[Binomial GLM using caret train](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25803960/binomial-glm-using-caret-train)

I am right in thinking that I can use the vote for outcome A as the 'y' variable, and the total electorate turnout (ie OutcomeA + OutcomeB) as the weight variable? Thanks.

(edit) The (artificial) data looks like:

```
OutcomeA OutcomeB   X1   X2   X3   X4
    1234     2345 0.23 0.34 0.34 0.45
    2345     2312 0.55 0.57 0.58 0.58
    3423     1234 0.45 0.88 0.69 0.12
...
```

OutcomeA is the number of votes in favour and OutcomeB is the number against.

I want to model the 'quantity' OutcomeA/(OutcomeA+OutcomeB) as a function of X1, X2, X3 and X4 using a binomial family model in glm, via caret.

The splitting of data into training and testing data is not the issues here.

Comment: I think what you are asking is how to divide your data into training sets with two possible outcomes. Where there are only two  A as one group, and the other group would be the total minus A,  which in this case is simply B. You only need to use a weighting method for the training and test data if you have a extreme differences in the number of observations for each of the two variables. And even then if you have sufficiently large data it may not matter. If I misunderstood your intent, rephrase the question or show more data and I will try to be more helpful.

Comment: Thanks. I have expanded the question slightly.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to model the ratio or percent of A, you could just use a linear regression and with the percent as your outcome variable (create the percentage before feeding it into the equation). You would get a series of coefficients indicating the impact of each X variable on y with a y-intercept.

Currently your data is not binomial, that would require a binary outcome, yes no, A or B, win or lose. Converting to a ratio or percent means it is not Poisson either that would need to be a simple count, a singular one.

If your goal is to predict a percent, the I would create the percent in a new column `(A/(A + B)` and use the new column as the outcome, with a traditional linear regression:

`mod<-lm(newPercent~x1+x2+x3+x4, data=df)`

If you have been tasked (in a class or something) with learning to use the glm with family="binomial" on this data set, then the simplest way to do it would be to use an `if` statement to ascertain the winner, create a new column with categories A & B to represent who won. Then use a glm as follows:

`mod <- glm(winner~x1+x2+x3+x4,data=df,family=binomial())`

But it is not appropriate model to predict the percentage of votes for A, that would be a traditional linear model.

If you want to use the method from your first link, then you would be using:
`mod <- glm(cbind(outcomeA, outcomeB)~x1+x2+x3+x4,data=df,family=binomial(logit))`

if you want to use the second link and are getting that error, using caret to manage the training and test sets, then you need to convert your outcome variables to a TWO LEVEL factor: `A or B`.

`df$newCategory<-ifelse(outcomeA>outcomeB, A , B)`
`df$newCategory<-as.factor(df$newCategory)`

Then use the glm in Caret with train and it should be fine. IF you are still having issues post the code update again and I will try to help

Comment: If the outcome is a probability, you can just use the weight parameter in glm(). I would advise against using a standard lm() when the outcome is a probability.

Comment: I also would not use `lm() for a probability. However the question was ambiguous, saying proportion, which is definitely not a probability and it could be modeled with a straight up linear regression. But then the question said something about using a binomial family in glm, which implies something altogether different. I answered two ways in to cover both bases...not because I was uncertain.